# problem passing listener class to a function

Tags: c++

I'm using a library that manipulates a binary search tree.  In this library is a function that traverses the tree and passes each node it finds to a callback class:

`bool TCODBsp::traverseInvertedLevelOrder(ITCODBspCallback *callback, void *userData)`

`ITCODBspCallback` is a base class in the library from which the user is supposed to derive his own callback class to pass to the function.  Here is the base class:

```
class ITCODBspCallback {
public :
    virtual bool visitNode(TCODBsp *node, void *userData) = 0;
};
```

Here's my derived class:

```
class MyCallback: public ITCODBspCallback
{
    public:
        virtual bool visitNode(TCODBsp*, void*); // defined in my implementation file
};
```

I then pass `MyCallback` to the function like this:

`bsp->traverseInvertedLevelOrder(new MyCallback(), NULL);`

and g++ gives me the following errors:

`expected type-specifier before 'MyCallback'

expected ')' before 'MyCallback'

no matching function for call to 'TCODBsp::traverseInvertedLevelOrder(int*, NULL)'

note: candidates are: bool TCODBsp::traverseInvertedLevelOrder(ITCODBspCallback*, void*)`

Anyone know what's wrong?  I'm curious why it thinks `MyCallback` is an `int*`, in particular.

Comment: Is your entire derived class shown above?  Or do you possibly have any conversion operators defined in there?

Comment: that is my entire derived class, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all looks like you forgot to include the `MyCallback` header. Since its parser doesn't interpret `MyCallback` as a type if it doesn't know it is one, it comes up with an own type, and ignores `MyCallback()`, i think. The type it comes up with is `int*`.

Notice that your code leaks because you need to call `delete` on any `new`'ed object. There is nothing wrong with creating objects like this:

```
MyCallback b;
bsp->traverseInvertedLevelOrder(&b, NULL);
```

In this case you are free'd of memory management.

Comment: My implementation file includes the header. Although, both `MyCallback` and the function in the implementation file that calls `traverseInvertedLevelOrder` are private members of the same class.  Would this have something to do with it?

Comment: @Max i think you should provide more code. Code like `struct A { void f() { new B; } struct B { }; };` is fine. So your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Changing my function call to what you suggested, as well as moving `MyCallback` out of its class, fixed the problem.  Not exactly sure why, but it was probably just a simple error on my part.  Thanks for your help.